# Which Airbus models have exterior LED lights? (Taxi, Landing, Rotating Beacon)

Tags: airbus, aircraft-lighting

I know that the Boeing 737 MAX has LED'S. Which Airbus models also have LED external lighting?

Comment: If we are talking interior then most newer Airbus models have full led interiors. Like the newer 320 models and the A350. http://www.aircraft.airbus.com/newsevents/news-events-single/detail/airbus-lights-the-way-first-a321-with-led-lighting-throughout-the-cabin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The A320NEO has full LED lighting. Check out the below link.
http://utcaerospacesystems.com/cap/systems/Interiors%20Documents/Lighting%20Systems/06%20Anti-Collision%20Lights/06_0010%20LED%20Anti-Collision%20Lighting%20System%20A320.pdf